# Sort auto update

Tags: google-sheets, sorting, google-sheets-query

I have this table, which is a ranking, whose values are updated automatically (data gathered from other files). What I want is that every time these values are updated the ranking automatically updates also.

**EXAMPLE**:

Table now

[image]

Table after one update, Frank has the higher score now

[image]

I don't want to go to the sort menu every time, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: @pnuts is gathered from another spreadsheets that my co-workers are filling, using IMPORTRANGE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This duplicates data (or since the source for the query is itself imported, even triplicates) but does seem to provide automatic resorting as data input changes:

```
 =query(A1:B5,"Select * order by B desc")
```

Comment: I've moved the data to a hidden sheet and I only show the QUERY, Thanks!